# Append object to end of list

Tags: python, xml, junit

Im using python with junit_xml to parse a logfile to produce a xml output.
My logfile looks like this:

```
/path/to/app1,app1,success,my@email.com,app1_log.log
/path/to/app2,app2,fail,my@email.com,app1_log.log
```

I am able to do append multiple TestCase objects to test_cases with the following code:

```
test_cases = [TestCase('app1), TestCase('app2')]
```

What i need is to go through the logfile line by line and add testresult[0] to the testcases object.

```
from junit_xml import TestSuite, TestCase

test_cases=[]

lines = open('testresults.log').readlines()

for line in lines:
    testresult = string.split(string.strip(line), ',')
    test_cases.append(TestCase(testresult[0])
ts = TestSuite("my test suite", test_cases)
```

The lineparsing part works fine, but i cant seem to add multiple TestCase objects to the test_case list.

Comment: what version of python are you using?

Comment: im using python 2.7.6

Comment: you can use `line.split()` `line.strip()` etc.. no need to use the string module. What is not working in your code? Your logic looks correct, are you getting an error or just unexpected output?

Comment: When a manually append two TestCase objects to the test_cases list it works fine. But when i parse the file in the for loop it does not.

Comment: can you share a couple of lines of input?

Comment: Your code can also be shortened to http://pastebin.com/NVwQz8q3

Comment: The input is what you see in the top:
/path/to/app1,app1,success,my@email.com,app1_log.log
/path/to/app2,app2,fail,my@email.com,app1_log.log

Comment: The code I pasted in pastebin works, how is it not working for you? Your own code also works.

Comment: Output using the two lines `(<junit_xml.TestSuite object at 0x7f149f57b790>, [<junit_xml.TestCase object at 0x7f149f57b6d0>, <junit_xml.TestCase object at 0x7f149f57b750>])`

Comment: It puts all the content of each line in the file in the TestCase objects. I only need first part before the ","

Comment: My code and yours only uses `/path/to/app1` etc.. The first element after splitting. If you `print(testresult[0])` you will see exactly what it is

Comment: Can you share the output that you get, there should be nothing wrong with the code. It could be shorter and use the `.split` as mentioned, but it should still work just fine.

Comment: `testresult = line.split()`
`print testresult[0]` gives me the whole line as output

Comment: @Phillez, sorry, should be `line.split(",")[0]`

Comment: Yes of course you'd need to specify the separator. https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Comment: Ah, right ofc. Thank you guys.

Comment: Note that your code is lacking a closing parenthesis in the line 
test_cases.append(TestCase(testresult[0])

Can you post the code that you actually run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing your code to the following, seems to work:

```
from junit_xml import TestSuite, TestCase

test_cases=[]

lines = open('testresults.log').readlines()

for line in lines:
    testresult = line.split(",")
    test_cases.append(testresult[0])

print test_cases
```

`$ python script.py 
['/path/to/app1', '/path/to/app2']`

Comment: did  you mean `append(TestCase(testresult[0]))` ?